# How can i create https connection with self-signed certificate on grails?

Tags: java, grails, ssl, groovy, https

i am using grails 2.2.2.
I must get info from backend via https.
I have 2 files(certificates) - *.p12 and *.cer

Thank you for your responce!

Comment: Please provide more info: what have you done so far, how are you communicating with your backend, what is the current issue you are facing

Answer (score 0):

For local development over ssl, you don't actually need a cert.  Grails will create one during runtime.  You just have to start grails with the https flag:

```
grails run-app -https
```

If you're talking about deploying a WAR to Tomcat, the only reason you would need to do anything extra in Grails is if you're using spring security (or some other plugin that may require some additional config).

Otherwise, installing a cert doesn't really have anything to do with Grails. You should look into installing a certificate in Tomcat.  If your server is fronted by Apache, you would install the cert in Apache.

Comment: thantk you for your responce!